# I'm having trouble assigning an initial size to a List<T> of classes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to initialize a list of objects (which are of the type Rep). Here is the code I am using to initialize the list:

```
        public static List<Rep> Reps = new List<Rep>(new Rep[6]);
```

Right now when I try to assign a value to a string in one of the list's classes like this:

```
 Repository.Reps[repnum].Main = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart,
 richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

I a null reference exception. What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any Msdn documentation about setting the initial size of a list.

Comment: You mean a list of _objects_ of type `Rep`.

Comment: This isn't totally relevant to what's causing your null reference exception, but by chance are you setting the Main property as that TextRange for all of the objects in Reps, possibly in a for or foreach loop?

Comment: No only for one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be getting your null reference exception because Repository.Reps[repnum] is null when you try to set the value of the Main property.  What your doing is creating an Array of Reps with a size of 6, but all the references in that array you are giving to the List are null.  Try newing up a Rep object and setting the Main property of it there like this:

```
Rep newRep = new Rep();
newRep.Main = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

Repository.Reps[repnum] = newRep;
```

If your intention is let all values in the List be null at first it might just be simpler to use the [List(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) constructor and create the List in this way:

```
public static List<Rep> Reps = new List<Rep>(6);
```

However, if your intention is to have your List contain not null objects when you create it you can create the List in this way:

```
public static List<Rep> Reps = new List<Rep>() 
{
    new Rep(),
    new Rep(),
    new Rep(),
    new Rep(),
    new Rep(),
    new Rep()
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative way to fill the list with newly created instances of the `Rep` object using LINQ:

```
var reps = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
            select new Rep()).ToList()
```

This generates a sequence of numbers from 0 to 5 (using `Enumerable.Range`) and then creates a new instance of `Rep` for each of the number (note that we don't really need the number `n` anywhere - it is used just to create some initial sequence of length 6. Then we can use `ToList` to convert the `IEnumerable` sequence to the `List<Rep>` type.

Alternatively using lambda functions explicitly (note that `_` is a valid name of a variable in C#, but it gives us a nice syntax that suggests that we're actually ignoring the argument):

```
var reps = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(_ => new Rep()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

The initial size is set correctly, it's what you put in the list that is the problem.

The expression `new Rep[6]` creates an array with six entries, but it will not create `Rep` instances for the entries, instead they are set to null.

So, you get a list containing six null references, not a list containing references to six `Rep` instances. When you try to use the `Main` property of an item in the list, you get a null reference exception.

If you want instances to be created, you have to specifically create them:

```
public static List<Rep> Reps = new List<Rep>() {
  new Rep(),
  new Rep(),
  new Rep(),
  new Rep(),
  new Rep(),
  new Rep()
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your list is initialized with 6 null references.

You have to assign a new `Rep` to each position.

Try:

```
    public static List<Rep> Reps = 
        new List<Rep>(new Rep[]{ 
            new Rep(),
            new Rep(),
            new Rep(),
            new Rep(),
            new Rep(),
            new Rep() });
```